# Updating php from 5.3 to 5.5

Tags: php, upgrade

I have tried to upgrade my php by using terminal. So far I have tried this `sudo apt-get install php5`. But I have no solution. Is there any solution to upgrade my php from 5.3 to 5.5 by using terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade php5
```

to update a packet   (ggf. with `sudo`)